# Data Mapper implementation in C#

Tags: c#, nhibernate

My Domain Layer is implemented with Domain Model, and after PEAA, in Data Layer I have to use Data Mapper.

NHiberbate is an implemantation of Data Mapper in C#?
What alternative I have to use Data Mapper in a C# project?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Using a DAL like nHibernate, or the newest Entity Framework will automatically give you a DAL and a "context" to work against... which means they take care of creating the DataMappers for you.

Well, up to a certain point. In nHibernate, you need to handle the entity to db mapping associations in XML, but I believe there are tools that allow you to do this. In Entity Framework, you have a designer in which to do this work.

Or, you can roll your own DAL, complete with persistence, data mappers, a repository, etc... but that's a pretty big undertaking. This book is a good one to use as guidance if you're going down that road:
http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780735626096/